# Large amount of data in ajax response and inconsistent reaction

Tags: django, jquery

I have an ajax call in `$(document).ready function` to get a large amount of data and show on page. It returns about 160KB data and takes about 6 seconds. Most of the time it works well but sometimes the error function returns error number `403`, `200` or `404` and it doesn't return data. I really don't know what's the problem. here is my ajax code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        URL='{% url CompanyHub.views.getServices %}';
        jQuery.ajax({
            url:URL,
            type:'POST',
            context: this,
            beforeSend:function(xmlHttpRequest){
                jQuery('#container').append('<img src="/static/loading.gif" id="loading" />');
            },
            complete:function(){
                jQuery('#loading').remove();
            },
            success:function(data){
                jQuery('#loading').remove();
                jQuery('#carousel').html(data);
            },
            error:function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                alert(jqXHR.status);
            }
        });

    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't have form element and after sending csrf_token as data in post options the problem was solved:

```
data:{csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'}
```

Answer (score 1):

you should first make sure sure that everything is fine server-side, i.e. 404 (not found) and 403 (forbidden) indicate that you're posting to an incorrect url. If your on using the django dev server, you can see the response code in the terminal. If you see 403s and 404s there, debug your server side code.

Comment: oh , U're right there's a CSRF verification error,but why?!! I've done everythong is required for an ajax call and I've never had such problem!

Comment: possibly you're using a newer version of django now. in either case, you can decorate your ajax views with the @csrf_exempt decorator, or read this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#ajax

Comment: @Asma check this link: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#ajax

Comment: @Hoff I have a reference to a .js file in template containing the same thing that u have reffered in that link,It always worked and prevented from CSRF error,but this time It doesn't.I don't know why It sometimes work and sometimes doesn't!!